# The local function 'RestartGame' is declared but never used Assembly-CSharp

Tags: unity-game-engine, delay, invoke

I really need help, when I put Invoke in C#, I have this error:

The local function 'RestartGame' is declared but never used Assembly-CSharp

I really don't know why it is happening, but here is the code:

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool gameHasEnded = false;

```
public float restartDelay = 2f;
public void EndGame()
{
    if (gameHasEnded == false)
    {
        gameHasEnded = true;
        Debug.Log("GAME OVER");
        Invoke("RestartGame", restartDelay);
    }

    void RestartGame ()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

unity manual: For better performance and maintability, use Coroutines instead.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html

Try someting like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool gameHasEnded = false;

    public float restartDelay = 2f;
    private IEnumerator coroutine;

    public void EndGame()
    {
        if (gameHasEnded == false)
        {
            gameHasEnded = true;
            Debug.Log("GAME OVER");

            coroutine = RestartDelayed(restartDelay);
            StartCoroutine(coroutine);
        }

        void RestartGame()
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
        }

        IEnumerator RestartDelayed(float delay)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
            RestartGame();
        }

    }
}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted flyingchris answer but just to explain your error message, I'm assuming its a yellow warning message, is that you are never calling the method RestartGame() directly anywhere in your code, you are invoking it however. Invoking is typically used for UnityEvents and coroutines are typically used for delaying a method.

Comment: Hi, I tried out the code, but for some reason it mess everything, please help

Comment: What does "messes up everything" mean? Are there error messages? And if so can you tell us which errors appear?

Comment: post what you got so far

Comment: if your using flyingchris code he has a syntax error, it should just be StartCoroutine(coroutine); instead of StartCoroutine("RestartDelayed", restartDelay);

Comment: Hmm... You are right. I'm changing the script. Sorry. I did not get any error message